# Using spam classification in a different application?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, text-classification

I want to use the concept of spam classification and apply it to a business problem where we identify if a vision statement for a company is good or not. Here's a rough outline of what I've come up with for the project. Does this seem feasible?

- Prepare dataset by collecting vision statements from top leading companies (i.e. Fortune 5000)
- Let *features* = most frequent words (excluding non-alphanumerics, to, the, etc)
- Create feature vector (dictionary) *x* of all words listed above
- Use supervised learning algorithm (logistic regression) to train and test data
- Let *y* = good vision statement and return the value 1; *y* = 0 if not good

Comment: Seems difficult but very interesting. Note that spam detection are historically done with simple models such as bayesian filters. My understanding is that 'good' here is a complexe notion; implying whether the vision matches the economic reality and is achievable for the company... You need a very precise definition of "good" and a complexe model (most likely involving deep learning) that will leverage as much information as possible on the company and the overall economy. Using logistic regression over an histogram is probably not gonna work (except if I misunderstood what "good" means)

Comment: Something more achievable using a word histogram and a logistic regression might be predicting if the vision statement is optimistic or pessimistic (not sure if that even exist) !

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are elements of a vision statement that make it "good". Like it needs to be audacious, inspiring, motivating, and futurecasting. At first, I thought maybe I could create feature vectors with words that were all of these things, but this idea seemed next to impossible. It would be awesome to sort of grade these vision statements in a way that not so subjective. Again thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm skeptical. The reason simple Bayesian filtering works for spam is that spam messages typically use a quite different vocabulary than legitimate messages.

Anecdotally, people who sell pharmaceuticals use the same words and phrases in their legitimate business correspondence as in some types of spam; so they get bad filtering results on pharma spam, while the spam filter quickly learns to correctly discard dating, Nigerian fraud, stock scams etc. (Pharma spam might still contain various hyperbolic phrases etc which set them apart even from non-spam marketing messaging, though.)

Business <del>bullshit</del> *lingo* tends to look the same whether the underlying plan is sound or not. You may be able to filter out the worst gibberish, but word-token level analysis is simply not a good indicator of whether actual sound thought went into composing those words into a particular arrangement.